# How do I render a bash script with the variables expanded?

Tags: bash, variables

How can you display a Bash script with its variables expanded. I want to see what the script would actually execute, **without doing anything.**

Comment: the options are mutually exclusive so beer all round

Answer (score 4):

There are three relevant options:

- `-n` - do not execute
- `-v` - show the code as it is read
- `-x` - show the code as it is executed

AFAIK, you can't see the expanded variables with `-n` in effect, but you can't avoid executing code unless `-n` is in effect.  So, roughly, you have to execute the script to see the expanded variables.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `-x` option of `bash` as:

```
$bash -x myscript.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't execute the variable assignments then there's nothing to expand.

Answer (score 0):

prefix your commands with `echo`?